# How to find a integer in an array using a Generics Method

Tags: java, generics, computer-science

I am still new to Generics and I am wondering why I can't do "if(b[m] > key)" its probably something very simple and I'm too tired to notice. But As you can see I am trying to find a certain number in an array of integers. What am I doing wrong? It has to be a generic method.

```
public class Question1<T>
{    
/**
 * This method searches through the array of integers to check if they match the key.
 * @param b array
 * @param key certain number
 */
public static <T> void search(T[] b,T key)
{
   int l = 0; 
    int r = b.length - 1;
    while (l <= r)
    {
        int m = (l + (r-l)/2);
        if(b[m].equals(key))
            System.out.println("Key: " + key.toString()+ " is in Element: " + m);

        if (b[m] > key)
        {
            l = m + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            r = m - 1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Not in array.");        
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Integer[] iray = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int key = 4;
    search(iray,key);
}
```

Comment: You can't compare objects with `>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because `T` can literally be *any reference type*. Let's say `T` is now `java.util.UUID` or `java.util.Scanner` or `java.util.List`. Objects of these types cannot be compared by `>`. Some can't even be compared at all.

So what you need to do is to constrain the generic parameter `T` to types that can be compared:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void search(T[] b,T key)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Now, you can call `compareTo` on `b[m]` to compare them. The method will return a positive result if `b[m]` is greater than the parameter:

```
if (b[m].compareTo(key) > 0)
```

Alternatively, you can add a new `Comparator` parameter to let callers of this method specify how they want the objects to be compared:

```
public static <T> void search(T[] b,T key, Comparator<? super T> comparator)
```

Then the comparison line will become:

```
if (comparator.compare(b[m], key) > 0)
```

Also, you seem to have (accidentally?) made `Question` generic. That is unnecessary unless you have some code not shown that is using it.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, Generics are not usable with primitives types (int, double, etc.), but only with Objects (Integer, Double, etc.). The boxed numbers (int --> Integer) cannot use comparison operator (except == but its behavior is not the one you want in that case). To resolve your problem, you have two solutions:

Make your T generic be a comparable (by defining ). Once done, replace

```
b[m].equals(key)
```

with

```
key.compare(b[m]) < 0
```

Note that it's not very optimized, due to the boxing of each value in your array. That's a troublesome limitation of Java. Currently, there's a work in progress to attempt to resolve the problem, and allow generics to be used with primitive values. It's called [the Valhalla project](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/valhalla/).

If you want optimized solution, you're forced to adopt the same strategy as in standard java.util.Arrays class : duplicate your etod for each primitive type, without using generics.

Hope it helps !